# Modelling a virtual team who is part of different products

Tags: team-management, project-management-style

I am managing a team which is delivering product A. There are other teams who are respectively delivering product B and C, managed by different managers. Each team has a mix of technology skills - mobile, JavaScript, infrastructure, .NET and java.

In addition to delivering product A, my responsibility is also with technology deliverables. I am responsible to ensure that nothing wrong happens with the technology that I own (say, .NET).

For leading this team who are under different managers but work on the technology for which I am responsible, I am trying to figure out what model/framework would fit the most.

Comment: This question needs a little TLC in order to avoid being closed as an opinion poll. Please provide some more detail about what you've considered, and why you don't think that will work for you.

Comment: Besides, I don't know if I'm missing something or there's no clear question at all on it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: Let me cite with some example . I am a delivery manager for a product line e.g email solutions - involves technology java , javascript, cloud services and infrastructure. Likewise there are other product lines e.g SAAS API integration which involves technology java ,cloud services  and infrastructure. Now the question that I have is how do I build a model/framework so that proper architecture/framework selection or code delivered in java are always upto the quality and standards. There are multiple product lines in the company.

Comment: What is your leverage over the other teams? Are you their boss as well? What would you do if Team B does not adhere to what you think is the correct use of the technology they use?

Comment: The other team members do not report to me. But as we all have the same code repository and same account for the cloud services we would want to ensure we follow the best practices. But in order to build that some form of either charter or responsibility matrix needs to be laid down across team members. I need help in building the framework so that each members who are part of the java technology adheres to it. It will be transparent and all delivery managers understand that this would be a good practice.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs : Please let me know if the provided information helps.

Answer (score 1):

A classic *Responsibility without Authority* setup, with one notable exception:

You want to have a say in the other team's code, and their PM wants a say in your team's code. So it should be easier to come up with some solution as it'll be bilateral and benefit all the other managers as well.

> I am trying to figure out what model/framework would fit the most.

It's called Matrix management, as you yourself commented, but the trick is not the model but making it work.

In your case it seems (without any other details) that all you want is a periodic Code Review of the other team's .NET code.

This is best done without the Project Manager present, to minimize friction.

So, for example, schedule a period, say *every Tuesday afternoon*, when each of the Managers sits with each team and Code Reviews their Technology. This may have to be done in serial if there's skill overlap.